# Short Story involving Time Travel and an attempt to change Man's Nature

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I want to say it was called something like 'Time Storm', but I haven't had any luck locating it.

The main character was (I believe) caught up in some form of storm that somehow unseated him from time, and dropped him into some structure (I believe it had non-euclidian geometry connecting the rooms) where a number of beings used some method to project their conciousness back in time to influence various historical beings.  This influence seems to be very negative, as they seem to be stoking the fires of Man's worse traits, making him more violent and so forth.

Our hero finds some way to attack them, end eliminate them from the structure, then sets about on a long chore of changing things back and making man a 'better being.'  After quite a while, he has accomplished his chore (this location being outside of time, I don't think he ages) and ends up re-inserting himself into time.

> Only to witness mankind being attacked and subjugated by aliens (possibly from outside of his time or something) now that man is harmless.

The twist at the feels kind of like Fredric Brown, but I haven't had any luck finding it.  Any ideas?

Comment: How old is it??

Comment: @user14111 - I don't know; I read a LOT, but I started snagging books from my father's library when I was a kid... It could be anywhere from about 5-10 years old to 100. (The 100 may seem excessive.. but then there are stories like '[The Machine Stops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Machine_Stops)' that I would never have guessed was from 1909 after just having read it...)  My best guess would be from the 60s or 70s.. But that's a wild guess..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were very close: this is *Timestorm*, by Eddy C Birtin. Apparently it's a translation of a Dutch story.

I read this in the anthology [The 1972 Annual World's Best SF](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?330496), and looks like it dates from the year before, 1971.

Comment: Excellent; I recognize the cover and have read many of the 'World's Best SF', so that fits.. And a synopsis of it from a dutch site confirms the details.  The cigar is yours!

Comment: Years later -- I just found my old copy of that exact anthology... and just re-read the story, confirming -- yep; it's the right one :)