Short story: typical 'time machine and kill Hitler' tactic backfires when the world is made peaceful and thus totally unprepared for alien invasion
I've googled this a few times and can't find it. Short story, 3k-5k words I suppose, likely published in the 70s-90s. I read it in the 80s or 90s.
Someone sees another human with a time machine creating Hitlers, Stalins and the like. (I don't recall how he witnesses this, only that he does.) Horrified, he takes over the time machine and goes back to undo all the creation of that kind of evil. The resulting 'garden planet' is peaceful, has no knowledge of war, and is therefore completely unprepared "when the black ships of the Vvorn" appear in the skies. Yeah, I'm pretty sure that's a quote, but no, I can't get search hits on any reasonable version of it.
I love the story for the anti-pacifist twist, which is actually plausible whether the evil would-be conquerors are aliens or not.

Now confined as a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/57286/short-story-involving-time-travel-and-an-attempt-to-change-mans-nature/57297#57297

This question is similar to: Short Story involving Time Travel and an attempt to change Man's Nature. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Daniel Roseman - I opted to close the other thread as the duplicate rather than this one, as your newer answer here provides more information about the story.

So the time machine did not show him that the aliens are coming?

This is probably "Timestorm", by Eddy C Birtin, previously the answer to this question.
I found a summary here:

In the year 2213 two wandering stars collide and cause a "timestorm."  Somehow this transports an Earthman, Harvey Lonestall, into a vast library of baton-sized cylinders, billions of them.  This "time tower" exists beyond space and time; here Harvey need not eat or sleep.  When inserted into a projector machine the cylinders each can transport Harvey's consciousness into the body of an historical figure [...]
Harvey kills the aliens and then uses the machines to manipulate history in a peaceful direction, preventing the rise of Hitler and Napoleon [...]
Harvey returns to 2113 Earth where he happily joins the peaceful vegetarian society of primitive hut-dwellers who have not even invented the wheel.  Then we get our Twilight-Zone-style twist ending.  Evil space aliens arrive and the human race is too weak to resist them!

The story is available on the Internet Archive. It ends:

And of course, this Earth was completely unprepared and unable to defend itself when the first black ships of the Vvorn appeared in the skies, out of the depths of an immense, big, and vicious universe.


Yeah, just checked it on the Wayback link you gave, and that is the one. Thank you! That is the FOURTH one, from either questions or comments, that I've seen solved around here just this evening since I joined. You guys have some skills.  :-)

Interestingly, I was just cleaning out my parents' apartment to get them ready to move, and came across the Wollheim anthology I originally read this in.

Anyone else bothered by "immense, big" why not just "immense" lol ?

@jo99blackops https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/repetition_commoratio.htm

Ironic that "Harvey kills the aliens" to move in "peaceful direction" ... then "he happily joins the peaceful vegetarian" .... though he himself is violent !!
